# Compact operator for which the image of the closed unit ball is not compact

Tags: general-topology, compact-operators

Do you have an example of a compact operator for which the image of the closed unit ball is not compact?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404516/image-of-closed-unit-ball-under-a-compact-operator