# The compactness of an operator from $C[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compact-operators

I'm trying to prove $T$ is a compact operator where $T$ is
$$T:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]  \text{ such that } T u(t)=\int_{0}^{t} u(s) d s.$$

But I "proved" that $T(B)$ is closed in $F$, which is not by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404516/image-of-closed-unit-ball-under-a-compact-operator).

Let $u_n\in B$, i.e. $||u_n||\leqslant 1$ and $v_n=Tu_n$. Then $\left|v_{n}(x)-v_{n}(y)\right|=\int_{x}^{y}\left|u_{n}(t)\right| d t \leqslant|x-y|$. By Arzela-Ascoli Theorem $v_n$ has a convergent subsequence, which means $T(B)$ is compact. Therefore, $T(B)$, being a compact subset of a metric space, is closed.

What's wrong with my proof?

Comment: Depends on whether the limit of the convergent subsequence has to be in $T(B)$ or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arzela -Ascoli Theorem does not tell you that $T(B)$ is compact. It tells you that $T(B)$ is relatively compact in the sense its closure is compact.