# Compact operator in Hilbert separable space attains its norm

Tags: functional-analysis

If $E$ is a Hilbert separable space, and $T:E\to E$ a compact operator. Is it true that there is an $x\in E$ with $||x||\leq 1$ so that $||T||=||T(x)||$?

Hints? Thank you

Comment: The image of the unit ball in $E$ under $T$ is, in fact, compact (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270862/compact-operators-why-is-the-image-of-the-unit-ball-only-assumed-to-be-relative)); it thus has an element of maximal norm.

Comment: So it is not necessary that $E$ is Hilbert and separable?

Comment: @JN_2605 You only need to have $T(\mathcal{B})$ compact and $T$ continuous with $\mathcal{B}$ the closed unit ball in $E$.