# Unit ball in $W^{1,1}((-1,1))$ is not compact wrt. $L^1((-1,1))$ norm

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega=(-1,1)$ and $B=\{g \in W^{1,1}(\Omega) : \|g\|_{W^{1,1}(\Omega)}=\|g\|_{1,1}\leq 1\}$. I want to prove that $B$ is not compact with respect to the $L^1(\Omega)$ norm. As a hint, I am given the following sequence of functions:
\begin{equation}
f_n(x):=\begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq 0 \\
      nx & 0< x\leq 1/2n \\
      1/2 & x > 1/2n
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

My problem is that my limit function seems to be in $B$. Here's my solution:

a) First, I show that $(f_n) \subset B$

Let $n>0$. By definition, $\|f_n\|_{1,1}=\|f_n\|_{L^1}+\|f_n'\|_{L^1}$. WTS: $\|f_n\|_{1,1} \leq 1$.

We have that $\|f_n\|_{L^1}=\int_0^{1/2n}nx dx + \int_{1/2n}^1 \frac{dx}{2}=\frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{4n^2}+\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2n})=\frac{4n-1}{8n}$.

Then, as $f_n'(x)=\begin{cases} 
      n & \text{, if }x \in (0,1/2n)\\
      0 & \text{, if } x \in \Omega\setminus[0,1/2n] \\
   \end{cases}$, I get that $\|f_n'\|_{L^1}=\int_0^{1/2n}ndx=\frac{1}{2}$ and hence $\|f_n\|_{1,1}=\frac{4n-1}{8n}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{8n-1}{8n}\leq 1$.

b) Now, I show that the limit of $(f_n)$ is not in $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ with respect to the topology induce by the $L^1(\Omega)$ norm, ie. $fn \xrightarrow[\text{}]{L^1} f$, but $f \not\in B$ :

Let $f(x):=\begin{cases} 
      0 & \text{, if }x \in (-1, 0]\\
      1/2 & \text{, otherwise.} \\
   \end{cases}$. Then
$(f-f_n)(x)=\begin{cases} 
      1/2 - nx & \text{, if }x \in (0,1/2n]\\
      0 & \text{, otherwise.} \\
   \end{cases}$. Note that it is a positive function, for all $n>0$. Thus, $\|f-f_n\|_{L^1}=\int_0^{1/2n} \frac{1}{2}-nx dx= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{4n^2}=\frac{1}{4n}-\frac{1}{8n}=\frac{1}{8n}\rightarrow 0$, ie. $fn \xrightarrow[\text{}]{L^1} f$.

But since $f'=0$ almost everywhere: $\|f\|_{1,1}=\|f\|_{L^1}+\|f'\|_{L^1}=\|f\|_{L^1}=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\leq 1$, which is not what I am supposed to get since it shows that $f\in B$.

What did I do wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your limit function is a step function. They do not belong to $W^{1,1}$, because their weak derivative does not exist as a $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ function, but only as a distribution (a multiple of the delta distribution in $0$, in this case).

Comment: Oh, thank you. I totally forgot about that. I’m not used to talk about weak derivatives yet. Could you just please precise what you mean by $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ please.?

Comment: Locally $L^1$: for every point there exists a neighborhood the restriction of your function to which is $L^1$; in this case, it does not matter much, tho. Bottom line is: step functions do not belong to $W^{1,1}$.

Comment: You may want to review the definition you were given of $W^{1,1}$, so that you can check for yourself if that function belongs to it or not!

Comment: I will! Thanks again.

Comment: General fact: no infinite-dimensional normed space has a compact unit ball.

Comment: Yes, you’re definitely right. But the purpose of my exercise is to familiarize myself with the Sobolev’s spaces, so I try to gain something from it haha.

Comment: @Henno i don't think that's relevant here

Comment: @Bananach at least it shows the result must be true.

Comment: @Henno No, since the question is about the unit ball in one norm being compact with respect to another norm. For what it's worth, i think this question is misleading, in that the actually interesting fact is that the $ L^1$ * closure* of the $W^{1,1}$  unit ball *is* compact with respect to the $L^1$ norm, by the Rellich-Kondrachov embedding theorem

Comment: On further thought, the question is not misleading, but rather serves as a counterexample to being able to replace "relatively compact" by "compact" in the definition of compact operators (you can replace that when the initial space is reflexive https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270862/compact-operators-why-is-the-image-of-the-unit-ball-only-assumed-to-be-relative, which the space $W^{1,1}$  in this question is not)

Comment: Thanks for telling! It helps!